# Why does jdbc use auto-commit true and jpa uses auto-commit false?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

Why does jdbc use auto-commit true and spring-jpa/Hibernate uses auto-commit false?
Why I am bothered about this is, both the api are used to more or less achieve the functionality. So why this different approach, there must be some reason - which I am trying to explore.

I understand what auto-commit is - each SQL statement is treated as a transaction when using JDBC with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale for JPA's lack of auto-commit support *might have been* that JPA and SQL have different *operation granularity*. Quite often, a seemingly atomic `EntityManager` operation like `persist()` maps onto multiple SQL statements (think cascade operations, secondary tables etc.). If such an operation fails, it is unclear what state the DB actually ended up in.

JDBC doesn't have this problem. Most of the time, there is a one-to-one mapping between JDBC operations and SQL statements, meaning that when an operation fails, the resulting DB state is still consistent and predictable.